# How to rotate a set of control points while masking

Tags: compositing-nodes, masking

I'm making another lightsaber fight.  It involves quite a bit of masking.  A lot of times, when I'm masking around an arm for example, the arm will somewhat rotate in the next frame. How come I can't press `A` to select all the control points, and then `R` to rotate them around their midpoint?  I can use `G` to translate, however, I cannot use `S` to scale (`R` and `S` only adjust the control points individually).  How can I change this?  Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select "Median Point" as the pivot point for the mask.

[image]